# Filter IP Range with Firewall on Internal Load Balancer + Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-vpc, google-cloud-load-balancer

was wondering if someone knows how to block the access from a specific IP Range inside a VPC to a Cloud Run instance connected through an Internal Load Balancer (ILB).

My setup is as follows:

- ILB (Serverless NEG) -> Cloud Run with Internal Ingress

Some examples for what I want to achieve:

- VM 10.10.10.10 -> ILB -> Cloud Run (Is allowed to access).
- VM 10.10.20.10 -> ILB -> Cloud Run (It **not** allowed to access)

I tried firewall rules but it seems the rule doesn't apply to Cloud Run and the ILB simply bypass it (even try with a `Deny all` rule for `0.0.0.0/0` and nothing happends).

Is this possible?, do I need another service to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you must combine VPC firewall rules and Cloud Armor rules.

First, you must create a VPC firewall rule to deny traffic from the specific IP range to the ILB.

Once you have created the VPC firewall rule, you must create a Cloud Armor rule to block traffic from the specific IP range.

VPC firewall rule must be created before the Cloud Armor rule.

If you are using a Cloud Run service with internal ingress, you must also ensure that the Cloud Armor security policy is attached to the Cloud Run service.

Comment: As my understanding you can't use Cloud Armor with an Internal Load Balancer. So this solution wont work